# What are the prerequisites for studying Automorphic Representation Theory?

Tags: representation-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-program

I am interesting in getting into Automorphic Representation Theory but am unsure where to start. It seems like there are a lot of prerequisites. What are the main areas (above abstract algebra) that make up automorphic representation theory?

Thanks.

Comment: Tony Knapp has an article about this, something like "Prerequisites for the Langlands program"

Comment: @Kimball This is a great resource, thank you.